# Execute Google Apps Script as anonymous only display the button "click me"

Tags: google-apps-script

i've a good google apps script that works well, it get parameters from GET/POST for produce pdf and send it by mail and store it in google drive.

all works fine if i execute that script by my user.

i've tryed to publish to everyone, keeping execution as my user
when i try to open the generated url i see only a button "click me"

what's wrong ??

i need to call this script from GAE for execute some stuff on docs.

anyone can help me?

this is the url of my script: [script](https://script.google.com/a/macros/onsrl.it/s/AKfycbzNBjVVgHZXhwrTULDyT2aoyjBp-Qgd_RTWgX2zu6AnKgQqcTTL/exec)

thanks
Sandro

**edit**

this is my test code:

```
   function doGet() { 
     var output = ContentService.createTextOutput() 
         .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT) 
         .setContent("Hello World"); 
     return output; }
```

i've publish as webapp, execution is set to my self, access is set to everyone including anonymous.

When i try to access as anonymous user, i always saw that button :(

Comment: it's hard to answer if you don't show any code... what is supposed to be shown ? What is it supposed to do ? Also your question title is ambiguous : do you mean 'anyone can run the script as yourself', even anonymous ? this means using your email account and drive ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. i've edited main post with sample code. thanks for helping me :)

Comment: i think i've found solution. when i've created my project i had choose "script as webapp" and not an empty project. with empty project, anonymous users can see correct result. I not understand difference, but i'm happy because now it work as i want.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't update the version (see the menu: File > Manage Versions) and then republish the app, so you were getting the old code (aka, the sample code you get from "script as webapp"). The test URL is always the newest code, but the real URL gets an explicit version.

Comment: thanks, i had found this things last night when i have tested the new script. i made a big mistake when i tried to deploy my script without read guide full :)